# Dynamically determine loadChildren module type from service

Tags: angular

In an Angular app, I would like to determine what module to load for a specified path. It's not about lazy loading. It's about dynamic route configuration/determination.

I have an app which have 3 kinds of access. Each access is in his own module. On app load, I would like to determine which module to load. At the root route level and the child level.

It seems to me that Angular is very flexible for many things but the routing configuration is very static...

Example:

```
// routed module
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => getModuleType() }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
class ParentModule {}

// My problem is there, where can I put this function?
getModuleType() {

  // How can I have the dependency injected?
  return someApiService.getProfile().map(profile => {

    if (profile === 'A') {
      return ProfileAModule;
    }

    if (profile === 'B') {
      return ProfileBModule;
    }

  });
}

// some feature module
@NgModule({})
class ProfileAModule {}

@NgModule({})
class ProfileBModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use guarded features module to achieve this.

Example of folder structure for Feature X folder and Core folder containing the guard (You can have N features if you want) :

```
/core
    /guard
        / feature-x.guard.ts
/feature-x
    /feature-x.router.ts
    /feature-x.module.ts
    /feature-x.component.ts
    /feature-x-home
         /feature-x-home.module.ts
         /feature-x-home.router.ts
         /feature-x-home.component.ts
         /feature-x-home.component.html
         /feature-x-home.component.scss
    /feature-x-route1
         /feature-x-route1.module.ts
         /feature-x-route1.router.ts
         /feature-x-route1.component.ts
         /feature-x-route1.component.html
         /feature-x-route1.component.scss
```

## Feature X

Each feature contains its restricted routes. `feature-x.router.ts` would be like this :

```
const featureXRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RouteXFeatureComponent,
    canActivate: [ FeatureXGuard ],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/feature-x-home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'feature-x-home', loadChildren: '@app/feature-x/feature-x-home/feature-x-home.module#FeatureXHomeModule' },
      { path: 'feature-x-route-1', loadChildren: '@app/feature-x/feature-x-route-1/feature-x-route-1.module#FeatureXRoute1Module' },
      // ... etc
    ]
  }
];

export const FeatureXRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(featureXRoutes);
```

@app is an alias for your source path folder. If you don't have one, use relative path instead. Lazy-loading is optional but i strongly recommend using it.

`feature-x-home.router.ts` :

```
const featureXHomeRoutes: Route[] = [{
    path: '',
    component: FeatureXHomeComponent
}];

export const featureXHomeRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(featureXHomeRoutes);
```

`feature-x.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FeatureXRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    FeatureXComponent
  ]
})
export class FeatureXModule {}
```

`feature-x.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-feature-x',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  styleUrls: [ './feature-x.component.scss' ]
})
export class FeatureXComponent {}
```

You can provide any layout relative to the current feature.

## Main module

`app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreModule, // contains all guards declaration

    Feature1Module, // feature-x with x = 1
    Feature2Module, 
    Feature3Module,
    //... etc
    FeatureNModule,

    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]

})
export class AppModule {}
```

If you don't have a CoreModule then declare all the guards here with `providers` property.

`app.router.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/defaultRoute', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/defaultRoute' }
];

export const AppRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

`feature-x.module.ts`:

```
const FEATURE_X = 'YOUR_FEATURE_X';
@Injectable()
export class FeatureXGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private profilService: ProfilService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const canGo = this.profileService.hasProfil(FEATURE_X);

    if (!canGo) {
      this._router.navigate([ this.profileService.getDefaultRouteFor(FEATURE_X) ]);
    }

    return canGo;
  }
}
```

With this system, depending on his profile, an user will be redirected on the correct "home" page. If he tries to access a page for which he doesn't have the right profile, he will be redirected to his "home" page

## Update

You need to use APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER hook for registering app routes depending on your user profile.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjfne6

Comment: I can't make it work, the navigation is canceled on the first false return from any guard. If the Feature1Module returns false on the guard, the Feature2Module guard is not called

Comment: If Feature1Module returns false you just need to get the current profil and navigate to its matching default route.

Comment: The problem I don't have any default profile yet. There is no public par on the website. Any authorised user is redirected to a login outsite the current website (OAuth) then is redirected back to the website with the token. So the only public route we have is 404 and 500

Comment: I was talking about each profile "default" route and not the app default route. Your redirection with the token targets a route like `mysite/someRoute` and then your client is able to tell if the current user can access this route or not. The instruction `this.profileService.getDefaultRouteFor(FEATURE_X)` is called when the user can't access a route and he is redirected to an allowed one.

Comment: I have set up a poc in Stackblitz to illustrate my case. Can you give it a look ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vd4oyu